# Return most common items in list

Tags: php, performance

I was wondering about the best way to return the most common items in a list.  So far the best way I could do it was:

```
//@param string $this->matched_ids_list = 1,11,12,11,12,
$this->matched_ids_list = "," . $this->matched_ids_list;
$this->ids_count = explode(",", $this->matched_ids_list);
$this->ids_count = array_unique($this->ids_count); //See below why this is done
foreach ($this->ids_count as $this->id) {
    $this->appearences[$this->id] = substr_count($this->matched_ids_list, ",{$this->id},");
    //[1] => 1, [11] => 2, [12] => 2
}
$this->most_appearences = max($this->appearences); //2
foreach ($this->appearences as $this->id => $this->times) {
    if ($this->times == $this->most_appearences) {
        $this->top_ids .= $this->id . ",";
    }
}
$this->top_ids = rtrim($this->top_ids, ",");
echo "tops = " . $this->top_ids;
```

It basically just works for `1,11,12,11,12,` and returns `11,12`, but it seems a bit overcomplicated. I've been at it for some time now.  Am I doing more steps than necessary, missing a built-in function or something?

I might be dealing with hundreds of `ids`, so performance is important.

Would this step:

```
foreach ($this->ids_count as $this->id) {
    $this->appearences[$this->id] = substr_count($this->matched_ids_list, ",{$this->id},");
    //[1] => 1, [11] => 2, [12] => 2
}
```

do more looping than necessary if `array_unique` wasn't used?

For instance, if `ids_count` was

```
[0] => 1, [1] => 11, [2] => 12, [3] => 11, [4] => 12
```

it would count how many times `11` and `12` appear on `matched_ids_list` twice. Instead, I use `array_unique` so `ids_count` is

```
[0] =>, [1] => 1, [2] => 11, [3] => 12
```

Comment: After the explode() call use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that, still a beginner. That makes things simpler, but I wonder if it makes things any faster. Any ideas on how to do some benchmarking?

Comment: Run the two solution 100000 times and measure time with microtime() (simple substracting will give you the delta T) but i have no doubt that array_count_values will be much more faster (built in C function, no string function used).

Answer (score 2):

### Skip to the Dramatic Update for the best solution

I was curious how to do this myself, because I could clearly tell there had to be an easier way! I started from scratch and I think I've found exactly what this question is asking for.

I don't normally just rewrite code, but since the question asks the best way, I believe I'm obligated to share what I believe is the "bets way".

```
$input = [1, 10, 11, 12, 11, 12, 18, 18];

$recorded = array_count_values($input);

arsort($recorded);

$output = [];

foreach ($recorded as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == max($recorded)) {
        array_push($output, $key);
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

I'll explain what's happening here:

1. We receive the input in `$input`
2. *`array_count_values()` returns an array using the values of array as keys and their frequency in array as values.* In our case, from `$input`.
3. *[`arsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) — Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association*
4. Loop over each pair in the newly sorted array. Create some variables to reference the current pair.
5. *If the current value is equal to the largest value from `$recorded`*
6. Add that key to the output!

And there we have it!

**Update to increase performance**

```
$input = [1, 10, 11, 12, 11, 12, 18, 18];

$recorded = array_count_values($input);

arsort($recorded);

$output = [];

$maximum = max($recorded);

foreach ($recorded as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $maximum) {
        $output[] = $key;
    } else if ($value < $maximum) {
        break;
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

We've stored the maximum so we aren't checking every iteration, and we're checking for a value less than the maximum so we can break out of the loop to prevent going through the whole array.

### Dramatic Update

So, I completely missed the [array_keys function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), as [pointed out by shudder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24446/return-most-common-items-in-list#comment99055_56282). The newly improved code would look something like:

```
$input = [1, 10, 11, 12, 11, 12, 18, 18];

$recorded = array_count_values($input);

$output = array_keys($recorded, max($recorded));

print_r($output);
```

Crazy improvement compared to the OPs original code!

Comment: If you're working on sorted array then Your loop is not effective. It should break after first rejected key is found. Add `$max = reset($recorded);` before loop and `if ($value < $max) { break; }` inside before `array_push()` (which is actually slower than `$output[] = $key;`).

Comment: @shudder I suppose you mean *efficient*? If so, I see what you're saying, however using `reset` has no benefit over `max`. Using `array_push` [could be slower](http://php.net/array_push), thanks.

Comment: After closer look it can be shorten to a 3-liner with `$output = array_keys($recorded, max($recorded));` being the 3rd.